# in conato <div id="footer"> in localhost is changing to <footer id="footer"> when uploaded

Tags: contao

I am using contao cms and I just installed it on ftp and uploaded the data from local host. 
The w3 validation was success in local host but now its giving errors on the uploaded page.
So I checked the source code in both the cases. and found out that the footer div is changing to `<footer>`
How can I make it as in the local host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will most likely be related to HTML5, Contao introduced HTML5 as of 2.10 . I'm a Contao dev and haven't fully made the transition so I can't comment beyond this. Though your solution of changing to strict will probably change it back to HTML4.

Answer (score 0):

I change the Output format of the particular layout to XHTML Strict. It solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This should not be an issue anymore. The w3 validator is now HTML5 ready. (It still outputs one warning, but only because the HTML5 Conformance Checker is regarded as an experimental feature.)